# Make a button alternate colours when clicked in HTA?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, hta

I am making a HTA application that will have buttons in it, I wanted the buttons to alternate colours when clicked (eg. orange/green), I found a script that worked with the .html extension but has a script error when run with the .hta extension. Please tell how to fix. (Yes, I need to stick with hta)

**Note, this is a [HTML Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application), and if the below code runs in a standard browser it will work just fine**

JS

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.select').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight')
  })
})
```

CSS

```
.select {
  background: rgb(255, 145, 0);
}

.select.highlight {
  background: rgb(26, 255, 0);
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <input type="button" name="Ignore Select" value="Ignore Select" id="select" class="select" />
  <input type="button" name="Ignore Delete" value="Ignore Delete" id="select1" class="select" />
  <input type="button" name="Ignore Insert" value="Ignore Insert" id="select2" class="select" />
  <input type="button" name="Ignore Update" value="Ignore Update" id="select3" class="select" />
  <input type="button" name="Ignore Sleep" value="Ignore Sleep" id="select4" class="select" />
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="my.js"></script>
```

EDIT: Images of the error, https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Q0a.jpg

Comment: And what's the script error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869408/how-to-make-jquery-work-in-hta-application

Comment: 1st: Script Error URL: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: @LGSon As you can see by this OP's HTML, his script is already after the `body` (and he has `jQuery(function($) {` anyway)

Comment: @user473470 That's not the error, that's just the URL of the resource. What's the *actual error*?

Comment: 2nd: The value of the property Jquery is null or undefined. my.js

Comment: @LGSon "Script Error" is the first error.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ex0mw9P

Comment: @CertainPerformance Posted an answer why it won't work

Comment: What browser / version? Works fine on latest Firefox 61 on Windows 7.

Comment: @Cypher You can't run HTA apps in Firefox, they run in IE, but the code above will work fine in a standard browser, though not the same as running as a HTA

Comment: @LGSon Oops. Thanks for the clarification. Didn't know people were still building things with that! My brain just replaced HTA with HTML. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason your HTA won't run that version of jQuery is because HTA by default runs in compatibility mode, as Internet Explorer 7, and doesn't support methods like `addEventListeners`.

If you add this alert to your `my.js` code you'll see which user agents gets printed.

```
alert(window.navigator.userAgent);
```

So to make it work you need to use IE7 compatible methods, or change the render engine.

To change engine, add this meta tag in your `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
```

Comment: @user473470 Try add this meta `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />` and let me know. If that is enough I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks! I just had to add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Answer (score 0):

why not just do this: remove the jQuery part in the beggining and replace it with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight')
    })
})
```

Comment: That didnt work, it just came up with a different error, "$" is undefined, and even if it worked, jquery.min.js would still come up with an error.

Comment: Ok so maybe you forgot to put in jquery script
do you have src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
linked in