# Implementing Datatables into an HTA

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables, hta

I have an HTA which loads in a large table into HTML. However, I want to take advantage of the jquery plugin for Datatables. However, when i got to run my script it gets an script error at line : `<script language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>` which makes me think I am not implementing jquery correctly. From all the post I have seen javascript files seem to be loaded in this way even for HTAs. It also takes quite a bit to load the 15000 rows so once Datatables is implemented and there is pagination then shouldnt the load time be reduced?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<style>
</style>
<head>
<title>ARMS Hamburger Site</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
var today = new Date();
var t0 =  today.getSeconds();
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
var connectionstring="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\\\path.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Persist Security Info=False;Mode=Share Exclusive;"

connection.CursorLocation=3;
connection.Mode=3;
connection.Open(connectionstring);

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);

var str=rs.GetString(2,rs.RecordCount,"</td><td>","</td></tr><tr><td>"," ");

rs.close;
connection.close; 
</script>
<center>
<table id="myTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td><script language="javascript">document.write(str)</script></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe you should use a newer IE version? Notice, that jQuery 3.X doesn't support IE<9 (you're running the HTA in IE7 standards mode). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567887/javascript-version-in-hta . See also https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: So i set it to the newest version similar to indicated in that post: <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" /> which should work since we have internet explorer 11 but i still draw an error for that jquery link.

Comment: What is the error message? It could be also a cross-domain issue, I'd make a local copy of the jQuery library, and loaded it instead of the online library.

Comment: The error I get is Script error , Code 0, URL: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js . I will give it a try and do the local copy.

Comment: Hey so i loaded it locally and it now tells me the exact error. Unable to set property '_DT_Cellindex' of undefined or null reference, and the url now points to the path I saved it at but still that jquery file . I am not sure what this means but its progress!

Comment: From googling it looks like there might be something wrong with my table?

Comment: So the end of my str string ends with<tr><td> so if you look at my html then that means I started another row with just one column. Any idea how I can account for this so it just doesnt create a new row like getstring tries to make it?

Comment: I don't think you can have that last `<script>` nested outside the `</html>` tag. 
The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869408/how-to-make-jquery-work-in-hta-application) suggests that all the script should appear after the `<body>` tag... worth a try :)

Comment: 1. Don't try and use Edge because your vbscript will no longer work.  Also, I noticed recently that vbscript is really slow at generating the html string so I don't think it's the data tables JavaScript that is slow.  I now pass data to a JavaScript function that is much quicker at rendering the HTML using append.  I may post a demo if you're interested.